# Failures when starting background tasks

Tags: uwp

I am having the UWP application that was converted from Windows Store app. Windows Store app was using ControlChannelTrigger. Now as I am trying to run this app on Windows 10 (converted), I find that background tasks fail to start. I see the following in the event log:

`The background task with entry point Background.KATask and name KeepaliveTaskForChannelOne failed to activate with error code 0x8027025A.`

`The background task with entry point Background.PushNotifyTask and name PushNotificationTaskForChannelOne failed to activate with error code 0x80070057.`

and similar.

My background tasks are registered and declared in manifest exactly the same as in **ControlChannelTrigger StreamSocket sample** in Windows 8 samples collection. What the first code means I have no idea. I know that 0x80070057 is invalid parameter, but what parameter is invalid, again I have no idea.

I googled and found nothing.

So, the question: what should I do to have my background tasks run as specified in Microsoft documentation?

What do these error codes mean in this situation?

Comment: If possible could you please share your code and the appxmanifest? Did you take look at this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974983/background-task-doesnt-start)? In general, this error means the app can not find the background task entry point from the assembly.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT thank you for response. Yes, I did take a look but it didn't help me.

Comment: Could you please share your code so that i can try to find out the problem.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT thank you for response. Yes, I did take a look but it didn't help me.

>In general, this error means the app can not find the background task entry point from the assembly.

I understand. My background tasks reside in separate assembly; I verified that this assembly exists within the package; I tried to create the classes from that assembly in my main app like this:
    auto s = ref new Background::KATask();

When viewing that code in debugger I saw that the object was created successfully.

Comment: Here is the code of my background tasks: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlaNKXNFDIJtsDR1LyofDdK3mQC7

Here is the manifest https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlaNKXNFDIJtsDVTRMTmJgIOJJ81.

Comment: I have tested with the code and manifest. It works for me. I registered the task with `ref new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType::NetworkStateChange, false)`.

Comment: Very good that it works for you. But I still have no ideas on how to make it work for me.

Comment: Which target platform did you run the app for? Could you please share your project?

Comment: My project settings are:  
target platform version 10.0.16299.0  
target platform min version 10.0.10586.0  
  
I am running it on the Windows 10 version 1803 build 17134.885.  
  
I would be glad to share the code, but I would like to get permission from code owner.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT The code owner says,  
"Yes you can share the whole project with him. But dont post it on stackoverflow. Some place private like email is fine". So, if you give me the email address, I'll send the whole project. Things like onedrive where everyone can download won't go.  
Thank you for help

Comment: Sorry, i can not provide an email. I shared a project that i integrated your background task into the sample(https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuOKNI7bIprOg7cEBg0atEgWTf2QaQ?e=MbgIam).

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT Thank you for sharing code. NetworkStateChange trigger works. The task Run method is successfully invoked. But I am mostly concerned with ControlChannelTrigger tasks.

Also, could you please explain what the error codes mean from my initial post:
KeepaliveTaskForChannelOne failed to activate with error code 0x8027025A.
PushNotificationTaskForChannelOne failed to activate with error code 0x80070057.


I know that the latter is "Invalid parameter". But what parameter is invalid?

Comment: ControlChannelTrigger also works.The exception in your origin post seems the endpoint can not be found. It is recommended you to share your project.

Comment: 1. What endpoint?  
2. Which options for sharing are available?

Comment: The background task endpoint. You can share the project via OneDrive or GitHub.

Comment: The code owner says,
As long as it's his onedrive or privately via github i have no problem with it.
(ie, it's private).


So, is there a way to share the code privately?

Comment: Sorry, we can not do that. Please share a simple project which can reproduce the issue in a public repo.

Comment: OK. What about my original questions? They can be answered without sharing code. 1. What do the error codes mean? 2. What is "background task endpoint"?

Comment: 1. I can not find the the message about the error code, it seems a random memory address. 2. the background task endpoint seems like a service endpoint which is used to call by other app.